# How to get answers by keys in JSON Mysql

Tags: mysql, json, nosql

I have a table with a JSON object. (Id,Data)

**Select id,data from myTable** returns:
`1,{"Key1": "Ans1", "Key2": "Ans2"}`
`1,{"Key1": "Ans3", "Key2": "Ans4","Key3": "Ans5"}`

I want to get something like:
`Key1:Ans1`
`Key1:Ans3`
`Key2:Ans2`
`Key2:Ans4`
`Key3:Ans5`
But I dont know what keys I have in data.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the rows back into your application and then write some application code to discover what keys are in the JSON blob, and loop over them.

Really, it takes like two lines of code in most languages (or 15 lines of code in Java ;-).

Don't try to make SQL do something it wasn't designed to do.